# Multitenant configuration: StaleObjectStateException on Transaction (hibernate + spring-data-jpa)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

i'm trying to setup a configuration for manage a multi-tenant enviroment with spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate and mysql (same schema, every tenant table has a tenant_code column). For dependencies the parent maven project is **spring-boot-starter-parent** (2.1.2.RELEASE).

On save entity hibernate throws this exception:
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) :

The highlights steps are:

1. Intercept "tenant code" with custom spring HandlerInterceptorAdapter (i read oauth2 token and extract custom attribute "tenant code");
2. Save "tenant code" in a @RequestScope bean;

   **On Save**
3. Define an custom hibernate EmptyInterceptor to intercept onSave action and previously set the "tenant code" (taken on a @RequestScope bean)

   **On Read**
4. In abstract Entity (extended by all my entities) i define @Filter and set it via AOP

If in interceptor i override onSave method i get this exception:

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.test.module.api.domain.entity.User#22]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2522) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3355) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3229) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3630) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:511) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3283) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2479) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:532) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:533) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.test.module.api.service.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$baf4f87e.updateUser(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.test.module.api.web.UserController.updateUser(UserController.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
```

**Here the code:**

**Spring Interceptor from Request Header:**

```
    @Component
    public class TokenInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
        public final String TENANT_CODE = "tenant_code";

        @Autowired
        private CurrentUser currentUser;

        @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
                throws Exception {
            String tenantCode = ... extract tenant code from request...;
            currentUser.setTenantCode(tenantCode);        
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**Class to setup inteceptor in hibernate:**

```
    @Component
    public class TenantHibernateInterceptorCustomizer implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

        @Autowired
        private TenantJpaInterceptor jpaInterceptor;

        @Override
        public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
            hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.session_factory.interceptor", jpaInterceptor);
        }

    }
```

**Hibernate custom interceptor:**

```
    @Component
    public class TenantJpaInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
        //Comment to test if problem is about spring context
        //@Autowired
        //private CurrentUser currentUser;

        @Override
        public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
            if (entity instanceof TenantAuditable) {
                //((TenantAuditable<?>) entity).setTenandCode(currentUser.getTenantCode());
                //if i comment this line everythings works (without tenant code)
                ((TenantAuditable<?>) entity).setTenandCode("TEST");            
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Service layer:**

```
    @Transactional
    public UpsertResponse<UserDto> updateUser(UserDto userDto) {
        UpsertResponse<UserDto> validationResult = CommonValidators.validateUserDto(userDto);
        if(!validationResult.isValidated()) {
            return validationResult;

        SpUser user = userRepo.findById(userDto.getUserId()).orElse(new SpUser());
        userMapper.mapUserDtoToEntity(userDto, user);
        try {
            SpUser savedUser = userRepo.save(user);
            validationResult.setEntity(userMapper.mapUserDtoFromEntity(savedUser));
            validationResult.setValidated(true);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            validationResult.setValidated(false);
            validationResult.setGlobalMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage());

        }
        return validationResult;
    }
```

I expected a insert/update sql query with filled tenant_code field.

**Here complete log**

```
2019-01-22 01:10:57.521  INFO 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-01-22 01:10:57.523  INFO 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-01-22 01:10:57.550  INFO 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 27 ms
Hibernate: 
    select
        spuser0_.user_id as user_id1_0_0_,
        spuser0_.created_by as created_2_0_0_,
        spuser0_.created_date as created_3_0_0_,
        spuser0_.last_modified_by as last_mod4_0_0_,
        spuser0_.last_modified_date as last_mod5_0_0_,
        spuser0_.tenant_code as tenant_c6_0_0_,
        spuser0_.buyer_id as buyer_id7_0_0_,
        spuser0_.email as email8_0_0_,
        spuser0_.family_name as family_n9_0_0_,
        spuser0_.given_name as given_n10_0_0_,
        spuser0_.middle_name as middle_11_0_0_,
        spuser0_.user_name as user_na12_0_0_ 
    from
        sp_user spuser0_ 
    where
        spuser0_.user_id=?
2019-01-22 01:11:10.689 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [2]
Hibernate: 
    select
        spuser0_.user_id as user_id1_0_0_,
        spuser0_.created_by as created_2_0_0_,
        spuser0_.created_date as created_3_0_0_,
        spuser0_.last_modified_by as last_mod4_0_0_,
        spuser0_.last_modified_date as last_mod5_0_0_,
        spuser0_.tenant_code as tenant_c6_0_0_,
        spuser0_.buyer_id as buyer_id7_0_0_,
        spuser0_.email as email8_0_0_,
        spuser0_.family_name as family_n9_0_0_,
        spuser0_.given_name as given_n10_0_0_,
        spuser0_.middle_name as middle_11_0_0_,
        spuser0_.user_name as user_na12_0_0_ 
    from
        sp_user spuser0_ 
    where
        spuser0_.user_id=?
2019-01-22 01:11:14.414 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [2]
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        sp_user
        (created_by, created_date, last_modified_by, last_modified_date, tenant_code, buyer_id, email, family_name, given_name, middle_name, user_name) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-01-22 01:11:23.137 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [3bf38f12-5d17-47e4-9504-ad0705289d10]
2019-01-22 01:11:23.138 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Jan 22 01:11:14 CET 2019]
2019-01-22 01:11:23.140 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [3bf38f12-5d17-47e4-9504-ad0705289d10]
2019-01-22 01:11:23.140 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Jan 22 01:11:14 CET 2019]
2019-01-22 01:11:23.140 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2019-01-22 01:11:23.140 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
2019-01-22 01:11:23.140 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [7] as [VARCHAR] - [gabriele.muscas@gmail.comx]
2019-01-22 01:11:23.140 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [8] as [VARCHAR] - [Muscas]
2019-01-22 01:11:23.140 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [9] as [VARCHAR] - [Gabrielex]
2019-01-22 01:11:23.141 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [10] as [VARCHAR] - [Giuseppe Pippo]
2019-01-22 01:11:23.141 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [11] as [VARCHAR] - [gabriele.muscas]
Hibernate: 
    update
        sp_user 
    set
        created_by=?,
        created_date=?,
        last_modified_by=?,
        last_modified_date=?,
        tenant_code=?,
        buyer_id=?,
        email=?,
        family_name=?,
        given_name=?,
        middle_name=?,
        user_name=? 
    where
        user_id=?
2019-01-22 01:11:24.912 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [3bf38f12-5d17-47e4-9504-ad0705289d10]
2019-01-22 01:11:24.912 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Jan 22 01:11:14 CET 2019]
2019-01-22 01:11:24.913 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [3bf38f12-5d17-47e4-9504-ad0705289d10]
2019-01-22 01:11:24.913 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Jan 22 01:11:24 CET 2019]
2019-01-22 01:11:24.913 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [PIPPO]
2019-01-22 01:11:24.913 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
2019-01-22 01:11:24.914 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [7] as [VARCHAR] - [gabriele.muscas@gmail.comx]
2019-01-22 01:11:24.914 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [8] as [VARCHAR] - [Muscas]
2019-01-22 01:11:24.914 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [9] as [VARCHAR] - [Gabrielex]
2019-01-22 01:11:24.915 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [10] as [VARCHAR] - [Giuseppe Pippo]
2019-01-22 01:11:24.915 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [11] as [VARCHAR] - [gabriele.muscas]
2019-01-22 01:11:24.915 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [12] as [BIGINT] - [23]
2019-01-22 01:11:24.918 ERROR 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.supplhi.buyer.api.domain.entity.SpUser#23]]
Hibernate: 
    select
        spuser0_.user_id as user_id1_0_0_,
        spuser0_.created_by as created_2_0_0_,
        spuser0_.created_date as created_3_0_0_,
        spuser0_.last_modified_by as last_mod4_0_0_,
        spuser0_.last_modified_date as last_mod5_0_0_,
        spuser0_.tenant_code as tenant_c6_0_0_,
        spuser0_.buyer_id as buyer_id7_0_0_,
        spuser0_.email as email8_0_0_,
        spuser0_.family_name as family_n9_0_0_,
        spuser0_.given_name as given_n10_0_0_,
        spuser0_.middle_name as middle_11_0_0_,
        spuser0_.user_name as user_na12_0_0_ 
    from
        sp_user spuser0_ 
    where
        spuser0_.user_id=?
2019-01-22 01:11:24.928 TRACE 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [23]
2019-01-22 01:11:24.940 ERROR 14304 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [com.supplhi.buyer.api.domain.entity.SpUser] with identifier [23]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.supplhi.buyer.api.domain.entity.SpUser#23]] with root cause

org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [com.supplhi.buyer.api.domain.entity.SpUser#23]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2522) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3355) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3229) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3630) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:511) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3283) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2479) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:532) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:533) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.supplhi.buyer.api.service.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$baf4f87e.updateUser(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.supplhi.buyer.api.web.UserController.updateUser(UserController.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
```

A little help, s'll vous plaît.
Thanks

Comment: Can you add code TenantAuditable? @GabrieleMuscas

Comment: Here the code of TenantAuditable:

@MappedSuperclass
@FilterDef(name = "tenantFilter", parameters = { @ParamDef(name = "tenantCode", type = "string") })
@Filter(name = "tenantFilter", condition = "tenant_code = :tenantCode")
public class TenantAuditable<U> extends Auditable<U> {
 @Column(name = "tenant_code")
 private String tenantCode;

 public String getTenantCode() {
  return tenantCode;
 }

 public void setTenantCode(String tenandCode) {
  this.tenantCode = tenandCode;
 }

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [(3.3) doc/sample](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html), You should implement your (jpa) interceptor like:

```
@Override
public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
  if (entity instanceof TenantAuditable) {
    for ( int i=0; i < propertyNames.length; i++ ) {
      if ( "tenantCode".equals( propertyNames[i] ) ) {
        state[i] = currentUser.getTenantCode();
        return true;
      }
    }          
  }
  return false;
}
```

I'am surprised that it worked with "TEST"...

Comment: Wonderful, it works!
From documentation, "onSave" returns true if the user modified the state in any way. This was my mistake. 

Now it makes sense! 

Thank you xerx593